# Solve the following initial value problems, $dy/d\theta= y \sin(\theta)$ with $y = 2$ When $\theta=\pi/2$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have been trying to solve it but i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
y'(\theta)&=y(\theta)\sin\theta\\
\frac{y'(\theta)}{y(\theta)}&=\sin\theta\\
\int\frac{y'(\theta)}{y(\theta)}d\theta&=\int\sin\theta d\theta\\
\int\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln y(\theta)d\theta&=C-\cos\theta\\
\ln y(\theta)&=C-\cos\theta\\
y(\theta)&=e^{C-\cos\theta}.
\end{align}$$
You said that $y(\pi/2)=2$ so 
$$2=e^{C-\cos\pi/2}=e^{C}.$$
Take $\ln$ on both sides: $C=\ln2$.

Thus
$$y=e^{\ln2-\cos\theta}=2e^{-\cos\theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Your equation is equivalent to

$$\frac{dy}{y}=\sin(\theta)d\theta$$

which becomes after integration

$$\ln(\frac{y}{C})=-\cos(\theta)$$
With $C=2$ to satisfy the condition $y=2$ when $\theta=\frac \pi 2$.

Finally
$$\boxed{y=2e^{\cos(\pi-\theta)}}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes it must be.